# Why does Monero GUI kill my internet connection?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I sync and I sync, for like 36 hours now to an SSD. Seems like the internet connection goes offline for the majority of the time I run the daemon. Turn the daemon off, internet comes back on. Any ideas?

edit: should I allow the port through my router? could be a stuuuuupid question!

Comment: With a decent internet connection and an SSD, the sync process could take under an hour if you're lucky.  Your issue is strange, and doesn't sound like a Monero problem, but I could be wrong.  You should not have to mess with ports at all.  It should just sync.

Comment: Does it kill it, or just use it at its max throughput, causing other net users to starve ?

Comment: There's too little information to respond with a proper "answer". There's a high probability that you are pegging out CPU and/or memory on your router AND/OR eating through all of the bandwidth. Try the `--out-peers` option in the daemon to reduce number of connections, and `--limit-rate` option to limit bandwidth use by the daemon.

Answer (score 3):

Many cheap internet modems choke when the outgoing bandwidth is saturated. Try starting the daemon with the "--limit-rate-up=X" where X is a small value in KB/sec. You can start by allocating one third of your maximum outgoing bandwidth and see how this behaves.