# Internet access lost due to DNS problems every time monerod starts

Tags: monerod

Every time I start monerod.exe on my Win 10 x64 machine, every device connecting to the same router loses internet connection. Even the notebook (MS Surface Pro 4) running monerod loses connection to DNS servers, and nothing has a connection except for monerod. Internet browsers return the error message: "DNS address could not be found." After stopping monerod, I also have to restart the router so that internet services recover. It also does not matter how much I restrict the traffic. This is way below the bandwidth we have at home, and it still kills internet in the whole household:

monerod --limit-rate-down=300 --limit-rate-up=10 --out-peers=1

Erdogan posted something [similar](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3676/2729) but probably not the same, since his internet connection recovers after stopping monerod, whereas I need to restart the router. Anyway, solutions suggested to him did not work for me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try adding `--no-igd` and see if that helps.

Another thing to try is to run with the environment variable `DNS_PUBLIC=tcp`.

In any case, it looks like a bug in your router.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. However changing the DNS server on my notebook to 8.8.8.8 solved the problem! Thanks anyway.